# Image button "onclick" change

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to make 3ximage buttons, 
It's like a normal nav.menu just with images. When image1 is active - show me image1-red, when image2 is active show me image2-red (but only active image is red not all of them) and etc

not background-image

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $(".buttons").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".active-img").attr("src", "images/homo-hover.png");
        });

        $("#button2").click(function () {
            $(".buttons").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
           $(".active1-img").attr("src", "images/nohomo-hover.png");
        });

        $("#button3").click(function () {
            $(".buttons").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".active2-img").attr("src", "images/homo-digitalis-hover.png"); });

    });      
</script>
```

Comment: I did not understand well your idea

Comment: So you want each button to change to a different image on click? Does 1 always change from A to B, B to A? Does 2 use those images as well, or does it use images C and D? If you change 1 to B, then click 2, you want 1 to remain on B (not revert to A) and for 2 to go from C to D?

Comment: It's like a normal nav.menu just with images. When image1 is active - show me image1-red, when image2 is active show me image2-red ant etc.

Comment: Need to see your html.

Comment: <div id="button1" class= "blocks buttons"><img src="images/homo.png" class="active-img"/></div>
 <div id="button2" class= "blocks buttons"><img src="images/nohomo.png" class="active1-img"/></div>
    <div id="button3" class= "blocks buttons" ><img src="images/homo-digitalis.png" class="active2-img"/></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simple way to do it..

```
    <div id="button1" class= "blocks buttons"><img src="images/homo.png" class="active-img"/></div> 
    <div id="button2" class= "blocks buttons"><img src="images/nohomo.png" class="active1-img"/></div> 
    <div id="button3" class= "blocks buttons" ><img src="images/homo-digitalis.png" class="active2-img"/></div>
       <script>
            $("#button1").click(function () {
                $(".buttons").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".active-img").attr("src", "images/homo-hover.png");

                // reset the other two images
                $(".active2-img").attr("src", "images/nohomo.png");
                $(".active3-img").attr("src", "images/homo-digitalis.png");
            });

            $("#button2").click(function () {
                $(".buttons").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".active1-img").attr("src", "images/nohomo-hover.png");

                // reset the other two images
                $(".active-img").attr("src", "images/homo.png");
                $(".active3-img").attr("src", "images/homo-digitalis.png");
            });

            $("#button3").click(function () {
                $(".buttons").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".active2-img").attr("src", "images/homo-digitalis-hover.png"); 

                // reset the other two images
                $(".active1-img").attr("src", "images/homo.png");
                $(".active2-img").attr("src", "images/nohomo.png");                   
            });


        </script>
```